# NGinx - Count requests for a particular URL pattern

Tags: nginx

I wanted to count the number of requests to a particular url pattern. Not sure how this is done in NGinx.

Is this possible:

When an request to the url pattern comes, we serve that request first. Then NGinx makes another request asynchronously to a server which counts the impression. NGinx does not wait for the response of this request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the post_action directive to trigger a sub_request after the main request is complete.

Useful for the sort of logging you have in mind.

## ** OCT 2016 UPDATE **

The post_action directive has been removed from the Nginx documentation and while it still appears to work, usage is inadvisable. Caveat Emptor!

## ** JAN 2020 UPDATE **

The [Mirror Module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html), introduced in Nginx 1.13.4, essentially replicates the post_action directive.

Comment: Is it possible to issue the sub_request via the post_action directive and not make nginx wait for a response.

Comment: Post action happens after the original request is finished. 1. Nginx processes original request and sends any output needed to the client. 2. When this is done, it issues post_action. As far as user is concerned, interaction finished at Point 1 and there is no waiting for post-action. As said, this feature was designed specifically for the type of thing you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this module

https://github.com/theromis/ngx_counter_zone

very close to your request