# Configure nginx proxy_pass with two parallel locations

Tags: nginx

Let's say we have the following quite minimal `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 443 default ssl;

  location /api/v1 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to use `nginx` itself as an event-source. Another component in my system should be aware of any HTTP requests coming in, while ideally not blocking the traffic on this first `proxy_pass` directive.

Is there any possibility to have a second `proxy_pass` which "just" forwards the HTTP request to another component as well while completely ignoring the result of that forwarded request?

Edit: To state the requirement more clearly: What I want to achieve is that the **same** HTTP requests are sent to two different backend servers, only one of them really handling the connection in terms of nginx. The other should just be an "event ping" to notify the other service that there has been a request.

Comment: How did you do this ? I have a similar scenario where I need to send request to two servers (A and B) and need to consider the response from server A only. As soon as the response from server A is available, I want to send back the received response to the client. Answers given below may no longer apply (not sure) to latest version of nginx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using [echo_location](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module#echo_location) directive (or similar, browse the directives) of the 3rd party [Nginx Echo Module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/echo/). You will need to compile Nginx with this module or use [Openresty](http://openresty.org/en/) which is Nginx bundled with useful stuff such as this.

Outline code:

```
server {
    [...]

    location /main {
        echo_location /sub;
        proxy_pass http://main.server:PORT;
    }
    location /sub {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://alt.server:PORT;
    }
}
```

There is also the now undocumented post_action directive which does not require a third party module:

```
server {
    [...]

    location /main {
        proxy_pass http://main.server:PORT;
        post_action @sub;
    }
    location @sub {
        proxy_pass http://alt.server:PORT;
    }
}
```

This will fire a subrequest after the main request is completed. Here is an old answer where I recommended the use of this: [NGinx - Count requests for a particular URL pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841622/nginx-count-requests-for-a-particular-url-pattern/9843473#9843473).

However, this directive has been removed from the Nginx documentation and further usage of this is now a case of caveat emptor. Four years on from 2012 when I gave that answer, I wouldn't recommend using this.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the explanation and alternatives!

Comment: @Dayo Given that the answer is bit old, what would be the best way (as per you) to achieve this ? Scenario:: I need to send request to two servers (A and B) and need to consider the response from server A only. As soon as the response from server A is available, I want to send back the received response to the client.

Comment: @user Have you tested the suggested Echo Module option and found that it is not working? There is also the Mirror Module which replicates the old post_action directive

Answer (score 6):

I know this is done but I'd like to answer with the new, updated answer since it's turning up in searches 3 years later. The mirror module works wonderfully. I got this from the nginx docs so I assume it's official and available.

```
server {
    [...]

    location /main {
        mirror /mirror
        proxy_pass http://main.server:PORT;
    }
    location /mirror {
        proxy_pass http://alt.server:PORT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the big advantage of nginx: you can serve from multiple backend servers. You must just include one more location, referenced by another direction. Here you got a sample of my sites-available/default, that servers from fastcgi (monodevelop), glassfish (java), static content & special error threatment. Hope it helps.

```
   #fastcgi
    location ~* \.(aspx)$ {
            root /home/published/;
            index Default.aspx;
            fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    #Glassfish
    location /GameFactoryService/   {

            index index.html;

            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:18000/GameFactoryService/;
    }

    #static content
    location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx_static_content;
    }

    error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 /50x.html;

    #error
    location = /50x.html {

      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;          
      internal;          
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want. I'm looking into sending the request off to two backends on **one** location. Edited the question to be more precise.